# Capturing pointer by value in nested lambda leads to segfault

Tags: c++, pointers, lambda

First of all, this is the most obscure problem I have ever had and thus is the hardest question to ask. I'll try make this question as articulate as possible by posting minimal code and providing some context. First of all here is the code where the problem occurs:

```
// Before lambda, pointer variable in question is fine
menu->onSelect = [=] ()
{
    window->pushCallback('e', [=]()
    {
        // Here the pointer captured changes, causing a segfault later on
    }
};
```

So now for some context:

The signature for pushCallback looks like this:

```
void Window::pushCallback(int key, std::function<void()> callback) {}
```

It stores a function to call when the key code denoted by the first argument is called, in this case 'e'.

Menu::onSelect is also a std::function, storing a single function to execute when a menu item is chosen.

Now the obscurity of this problem is that the pointer only changes on the second time stepping through the code. Note that this is an interactive ncurses program. However I have done much testing and have found the pointer changes between the two shown comment lines. Showing that the mutation occurs through capturing the variable in the nested lambdas. I have also made the pointer const in all classes that refer to it.

Comment: When the lambda executes, are the pointers still valid? Are the objects they point to still alive?

Comment: Which pointer ? `menu`, `window`, some other pointer ?

Comment: Please present your [MCVE]. That's very important for questions like this.

Comment: Oh and compiler/toolchain version / OS etc are all important.

Comment: The pointer becomes invalid when it randomly changes in the inner lambda. The data it points to is not deleted. The actual variable is irrelevant as it is definitely the lambda capture that is mutating the pointer variable. I've omitted it on purpose.

Comment: You don't know what the problem is, and therefore do not know what is and isn't relevant. Present your [MCVE], on purpose.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It is hard to provide an MCV because of how big the application is. The fact the pointer mutation only happens on the second time through means you will unlikely encounter the problem outside of the application. I can only offer the github links and you can execute the program yourself. I was hoping for the problem to be how I was using the nested lambdas.

Comment: The fact that your application is big is precisely _why_ you need to compose a MCVE. Until you have done so, neither you nor we know that there is not some UB elsewhere in your code that causes the problem. I know it can be an arduous process to compose a MCVE, but that is part of your job of debugging and you must now perform it please. I can at least confirm that (to the best of my knowledge) there is no outright logical problem with your lambdas .... but, then again, we can _barely_ see how they're being composed or used. VTC until that is done due to your reluctance after being asked twice

Answer (score 0):

<del>You cannot use automatic member capture in nested lambdas like that because the inner lambda's capture isn't performed until the outer lambda is executed.</del> I believe that the are some differences between pre-C++14 and C++14/17 but I don't remember off-hand. I'll look into it and update my answer.

Also, I vaguely remember running into some differences between G++ and Clang, but that had to do with the compiler complaining, not with implementation differences that would cause a segfault. Again, I'll update once I can remember.

---

Work around, explicitly capture the variable or save it in a tmp variable.

```
std::shared_ptr<int> ptr; // This assumes that you are talking about shared pointers since I don't think you would have this problem with raw pointers unless the object is being destroyed before your lambda is being invoked
auto x = [ptr]()
     {
         // You could also create a temporary variable here to avoid ambiguity
         // std::shared_ptr<int> ptr2;
         return [ptr]() { return ptr; };
     };
```

---

I verified that my original hypothesis is wrong. Shared points work properly in this case (but make sure you're not passing by reference or all bets are off).

```
auto foo(std::shared_ptr<int> p)
{
    return [=](int x) { return [=](int y) { return *p + x + y; }; };
}

int main()
{
    auto p = std::make_shared<int>(42);

    auto func = foo(p);

    std::cout << func(1)(2) << std::endl;

    ++(*p);

    std::cout << func(1)(2) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I recommend looking at the error in gdb and possibly setting a hardware break on the pointer if you are concerned that it is being changed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, if you could provide a work-around I'll make this the accepted answer!

Comment: I'm not completely convinced by this. Either the pointer is captured, or it isn't. If it isn't, the program would not compile. (Of course, there could be a bug.) Please show an example.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit your examples are completely valid for plain old datatypes but my hypothesis is that the pointer is a shared_ptr instead of a raw pointer and that something is corrupting the reference count. Example to come

Comment: @JimPri: That would have to be a stdlib impl bug, as far as I can tell. I'm not saying it's not the case, but we will need more to go on. Awaiting your update! :) I have at least showed that the capture, in standard terms, and contrary to the start of your answer, is perfectly valid (or at least that its invalidity fails silently in current GCC)

Comment: If you no longer think the answer is correct, you can delete it.